# In C/C++ how many decimal places is the product / quotient of 2 doubles accurate to

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

If I have 2 doubles x and y and do z = x / y or z = x * y is the result accurate to 15 decimal places?

Edit: sorry, x and y and between 0 and 1.

Comment: It depends, what are `x` and `y` values?

Comment: It depends on how accurate are the values you put in.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Actually a better question than one may think at first sight: "Is the last digit correct?" (Note that double accuracy is "15 to 17" digits, in decimal notation. But still.)

Comment: Do you mean number of digits, or do you mean the number of digits to the right of the decimal point?

Comment: `2/3` shows `0.6666666666666666296592325`; is the 15th decimal digit "accurate"? (Depending on how you count. For me the 16th is another `6`, then a `2` follows.)

Comment: C++ doesn't specify this, leaving it up to whatever is most efficient for the host system, but most modern CPUs use the [IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard which you can consult.

Comment: @cdhowie that article looks quite helpful thanks!

Comment: just keep in mind that `c/c++` is not a language

Comment: Assuming that none of the numbers are so close to zero that they are "denormalized", then the result of a multiplication or division will always be accurate to 53 bits (the mantissa portion) rounded. If doing addition or subtraction, then the smaller number's mantissa will be shifted right by the difference in the exponents, in which case accuracy is lost, mostly noticeable if summing up a large set of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the 2 input numbers are considered to be without error ....

If using [binary64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) for `double` and competent division/multiplication, the result should be expected correct within 1/2 the [unit in the last place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) given the typical default of round-to nearest mode of the exact mathematical result.

The maximum relative error would be 1/2 bit in power(2,53) or 5.55e-17.  But printing a `double` in decimal has its issues.

`scanf` can correctly convert all `N` significant decimal digit combinations into a `double` and back into the same string as long as `N` is at most `DBL_DIG`.  This is 15 for binary64 `double`.

The relevant equation is in C11 §5.2.4.2.2 12. "floor((p-1)* log10 b)" --> `floor((53-1)*log(2))` --> `floor(15.65)` --> `15`.

Since our product/quotient is only accurate to 52.5 binary digits: `floor((52.5-1)*log(2))` -> `floor(15.35)` --> `15`.

IMO: The answer is correct to 15 significant decimal places.

Note: That is often written as a leading digit, decimal point and more 14 digits times some power-of-10.

[Edit]

Should be "only accurate to 53.5 binary digits:"  `floor((53.5-1)*log(2))` -> `floor(15.80)` --> `15`.  Same end result.